# Technique to measure the volume of a crystal

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I am doing a project on crystal growth. I am making potash alum in two different conditions, one in the fridge and the other one in room temperature. I wanted to how can I measure their volume? Techniques?

Comment: Submerge in liquid, note change in total volume. 3D laser mapping. Mass and lattice parameter measurements.

Comment: weigh 'em. Volume = mass/density

Answer (score 1):

Potash alum is soluble in water (~14g/100mL at 20C) but not in acetone. I would submerge the sample in a known volume of acetone and measure displacement. If you want to be super thorough, cool the acetone first.

I wouldn't use reported density because you don't necessarily know if you made a pure product etc.

Comment: Good solution.  I'd also be sure to give the crystal a good rinse on filter paper with acetone to prevent adding water and dissolved potash alum to your volumetric measurement setup; any residual dissolved potash alum will precipitate out to give you an increased mas of precipitate.  For that matter, just the excess water would give you a high-bias in your measurement. Probably negligibly  small, but it doesn't hurt.  Also, since you need to dry the crystals before measuring their volume anyway, an acetone rinsed crystal will be much easier to dry than a crystal soaked in water.

Comment: I'd wonder if the OP is going to get one nice crystal or some massive crystal cluster. So measuring the volume is trickier than one might suppose. The dang air bubbles...

Comment: @MaxW, I don't know what equipment OP has available, but do you think an ultrasonic bath might help with the air bubbles?  I guess it would also destroy a nice big crystal or otherwise degrade the quality of the crystals in a way OP doesn't want.